# Getting an error message to show up inline of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added the jQuery validate plugin to validate a contact form I have, but I am running into an issue. I am trying to get my error class to show up inline of the input field in which the error is. However, it is only displaying in block. I know this is because I have `display: block !important;` for my input class, but if I take that away, it moves my blocks inline whenever there is an error.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Please look in the comments to see a jsfiddle. I was unable to figure out how to insert an external source in the snippet.

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="" novalidate>
  <input class="contact_input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input class="contact_input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <textarea class="contact_input" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submitform" value="Send">
</form>
```

CSS

```
.contact_input {
  display: block !important;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 300px;
}
.error {
  color: red;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/wgtLnxfw/#&togetherjs=fapCA8gcgc

Comment: Is this something you want to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/wvo76vbr/

Comment: Yes, except the message block gets all out of wack.

Comment: Try it now: https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/wvo76vbr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I think the following CSS works:

```
    .contact_input {
      display: block !important;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      width: 300px;
    }
    .error {
      color: red;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .clear {
      clear: both;
      padding: 10px;
      display: block;
    }
```

Please let me know if it works for you too.

EDIT: 
Please let me know if this works: https://jsfiddle.net/wgtLnxfw/6/
It has changes to mark up and css.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the markup and css as below.
Check demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/wvo76vbr/)

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="" novalidate>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" name="submitform" value="Send">
    </div>
</form>


#contactform input[type="text"], input[type="email"], textarea {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}

#contactform div {
  overflow: auto
}

.error {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Why won't the error class take on a padding/margin? Whenever I try to add one it adds the margin/padding to the inputs?

Comment: Actually, the `error` class is added to both `input` and `label`. So I changed css from just `.error` to `label.error`. Now it works only for error messages - check same fiddle.